# Which part of iPhone is responsible for radiation

Tags: iphone, battery

I wonder what part of the iPhone is responsible for the radiation? Is it battery?

Comment: The two answers demonstrate the imprecision of the question's use of the word "responsible." If the OP meant "what _creates_ the electromagnetic radiation, then the transmitter part of the iPhone's transceiver is responsible. If the OP meant _what allows or facilitates_ the electromagnetic radiation being sent out into the world, then the various radio antennas are responsible. Both pieces are necessary for effective radio communication.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I suggest put both of them in the question, and if 2-3 people vote all the posts here, it might hit HNQ too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is [ambiguous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ambiguous). There are many different types of [radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation), but you didn't specify which type. [@MikeScott has indicated](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381781/149366) the iPhone's primary sources of *radio frequency* radiation in his answer, but these are not the only ones.

- the screen radiates electromagnetic radiation in the form of light
- the battery radiates heat which is also a form of electromagnetic radiation
- all of the circuitry in the iPhone radiates electromagnetic radiation in the form of radio waves and heat
- the speakers radiate acoustic waves

So there are many components in an iPhone responsible for radiation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it is very detailed. I changed the battery of the iphone with the help of an repair service and did worry a bit about the Battery.

Answer (score 3):

By radiation, I'm assuming you mean the creation of electromagnetic waves and not the movement of sub-atomic particles like X-Rays.

In that case, it would be the transmitter (technically the [transceiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transceiver) since it's an all in one device).  It's the transmitter that generates the electromagnetic waves at their respective frequencies with embedded data through the antennas that creates this radiation.

### How a Transmitter Works

[image: Transmitter Picture]

There's three components to a transmitter

- Oscillator creates the "carrier wave" at a specified frequency.  This is the LTE, GSM or PCS frequencies that your carrier (AT&T, Sprint, Verizon, etc.) uses.
- Modulator embeds all of the data onto the wave signal generated by the oscillator
- Amplifier (with antenna) takes that signal and increases it's power so that it's strong enough to reach the closest receiver.

### Particle Radiation

If you're referring to the movement of sub-atomic particles from your iPhone, there isn't any.  There's no component (like the battery you mentioned) with any degree of radioactivity (This is the "dangerous radiation").  It would be illegal to sell that to the general public.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! Very informative!

Answer (score 0):

It’s the radio antennas. It has to radiate in order to communicate with mobile phone networks, wifi networks, Bluetooth devices, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The only form of radiation emitted by a phone which has any significant amount of energy is the radio transmitter which talks to the tower.  It is a very weak signal, but there are those who suggest that it is unhealthy to hold your phone up next to your *brain.*

I don't worry about that, personally, with my phone, but when I'm using my HAM radio "HT," I do always use a microphone since the power of that transmitter might be as high as five watts.